# Why do I get a runtime error after I linked a shared library in a non-standard location?

Tags: linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm new to Linux. I wrote an application that uses MySQL, and its Makefile is posted as follows:

```
OBJ = main.o PeerDbOpMgr.o
MYSQL_INC = ./mysql/include
LNK_MYSQL = ./mysql/lib/ -lmysql

main : $(OBJ) 
    g++ -g -o main $(OBJ) -L$(LNK_MYSQL) -lpthread -lm

main.o : main.cpp
    g++ -g -c -I$(MYSQL_INC) main.cpp


PeerDbOpMgr.o : PeerDbOp.cpp PeerDbOp.h
    g++ -g -c -I$(MYSQL_INC) PeerDbOp.cpp -o PeerDbOpMgr.o

clean : 
    rm main $(OBJ)
```

I compiled it successfully.  But when I ran it, it showed an an error:

> ./main: error while loading shared libraries: libmysql.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The `libmysql.so.16` file is under `./mysql/lib/libmysql.so.16`, but why does it says that there's no such file or directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have linked your application to a library that is not in the runtime linker's path. Your application should work when you run it like:
`env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./mysql/lib ./main`

Manpages to read:
ld(1), ldconfig(8)